# On the inconsistent stroke order for 右 and 左

Tags: stroke-order, stroke-type

In the manga *Tomehane!*, which revolves around a high school calligraphy club, there's a rather convoluted historical explanation for the differing stroke order of the "right" and "left" kanji in the standard script on the basis of their sources in the older seal script:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry for being dense, but I can't fully wrap my head around sensei's argument. Which parts of the seal script characters are supposed to correlate one-to-one with which parts of 右 and 左?

Comment: The sensei redrew the first stroke of each character saying "here".